# Nodejs handling login on another server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

suppose you had 4 machines each running an instance identical nodejs app, and users have to log in to access your website, after a user logs in is it possible to move his connection to one of the other machines?

To Clear it up:
[image]

1. Node 1 only holds the main app page, handles login validation and
   knows how many users are on each node, and it routes the user who
   logs in to the Node with the lowest number of users, or to make it
   more complicated to the server which has the lowest load(not based
   on the number of users but the traffic).
2. each of the other Nodes run CentOS with a nodejs server instance
   cluster of Node processes.
3. i am using socket.io intensively and after login i always have
   presistant connection with the client,even on my client no ajax
   requests are made, everything is handled using sockets.
4. in my current source code, everything is combined in one nodejs app,
   and i do socket authentication for login
5. The clients have no kind of interaction with each other, which makes the job easiear.

is it possible to pass a socket connection from one nodejs server to another?

how would you solve this problem yourself, considering that the nodejs app that handles the login and the actual nodejs app are 2 seperate machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it simple. I would create a load balancer node with its own application balancer application. This node will redirect to the less loaded "worker" node.js instance based on the number of authenticated use sessions on each node. This should happen even before authentication is done. All other "worker" nodes will have same main app with exactly same logic running - main page, authentication and application logic.

Comment: problem is this application is so data intensive the client interface is updated each seconds, thats why i have to presist connections, and one node server is not enough anymore, node cluster helped alot but it got to a point where one machine is not enough, so i need to handle instances that are not on the same machine

Comment: Maybe I do not see the whole picture, but you need load balance once, before login is done. After login client stays with the same instance. You are not forwarding different requests from same client to different nodes, right? If so, this should not be a problem. If you need node instances with pure "socket" logic, then a solution  with access token is the best one.

Comment: yes after a client gets authinticated node1 will point him to one of the nodes from 2-5 and he will stay there, i have no interaction between nodes from 2 to 5

Answer (score 2):

Just save an access token (i.e. cookie in case of http) into a database and send it from the client to the server every time it connects.

Comment: agreed. Simplest method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's tough to give a complete answer without having a better sense of your application's architecture... but I'll lay out my assumptions and go from there:

a) www.yourdomain.com points to `Node 1`.

b) `Node 1` is the only server that responds to HTTP requests, `Node 2` through `Node 5` only communicate through sockets.

c) Once a user is authenticated through `Node 1`, it does not need to re-authenticate through `Node 1` for subsequent communication through sockets (this one is a bit tricky, if you really want to ensure that only authenticated users can access your app that authentication must be passed over the socket connection, but it can be simpler than the full authentication performed by `Node 1`, and it sounds like you're doing this, just want to raise the issue)

Given those assumptions, then I would assign subdomains to each app server (perhaps node2.yourdomain.com, node3.yourdomain.com, etc?), then when `Node 1` is ready to pass the client over to the app server, determine which node you want to send them to, pass that subdomain over to the client, and have the client create a socket connection to the assigned app server, then all of its communication will happen through there.

If I've misunderstood or over-simplified things, feel free to set me straight in comments.

Comment: you got it exactly right, after login node1 has nothing to do with the client anymore , the client will get connected to one of the nodes from 2-5, on log out the users get redirected to node1, i have many ways to handle it but i am no expert, but i like the idea of sub domains simplifies things alot.